# How to generate series in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to generate table with *say* 600 consecutive numbers (starting with 51) in each row
How I do this with BigQuery Standard SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT 50 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num
FROM UNNEST((SELECT SPLIT(FORMAT("%600s", ""),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL))) AS pos
ORDER BY num
```

BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT 50 + pos AS pos FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, * 
  FROM (FLATTEN((SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 600, '.'),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL)), h))
) WHERE pos BETWEEN 1 AND 600
```

From there you can adjust logic *for example* to get consecutive days and other sequences

Comment: I have something much nicer in the pipeline for standard SQL--unfortunately it isn't available yet :( I'll bookmark this post and add an answer once I have something to share.

Answer (score 39):

Try `GENERATE_ARRAY` in standard SQL:

```
SELECT num FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(51, 650)) AS num;
```

Edit: if you want more than about a million elements, you can use multiple calls to `GENERATE_ARRAY`, although be warned that the query can end up taking a long time if you produce too many elements:

```
SELECT num1 * num2 AS num
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1000000)) AS num1,
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) AS num2;
```

Comment: @Elliott Brossard, it looks like `GENERATE_ARRAY` is limiting the sequence length to exactly `1048575`, which is `2^20 - 1`. Do you know what that limit is for or where it comes from? My use case involves generating a sequence from 1 to 5 billion entries long. I'm working around it by writing the sequence to a bucket in CSV format, and importing to a table from there.

Comment: I added this limit with a comment that says, `Enforce a hard limit of around a million elements to avoid generating arrays that are too large for constant folding or other parts of the runtime.` I didn't want to make it easy to create arrays that would cause your query to fail. See my updated answer, though.