# Generate series / range / array in SQL (Big Query) with min and max values taken from another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to generate table `t1` with N consecutive numbers in each row, starting with the smallest value in another table `t` and ending with the largest value in the table `t`.

How I do this with Big Query Standard SQL?

For simplicitys sake, imagine `t` is created in the following way (except that you do not know the start and end value beforehand)

```sql
SELECT num FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(51, 650)) AS num;
```

Somehow I would like to do something to the effect of

```sql
SELECT num FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(MIN(t.num), MAX(t.num))) AS t1;
```

This question is very similar to [1], with the difference that the start and end of the series dependent on the min/max values of another table.

[1] [How to generate series in BigQuery Standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884708/how-to-generate-series-in-bigquery-standard-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT tt
FROM (SELECT MIN(t.num) as min_num, MAX(t.num) as max_num
      FROM t
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(t.min_num, t.max_num)) tt
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

If I understand correctly, you name the statement `(SELECT MIN(t.num) as min_num, MAX(t.num) as max_num)` `t`, but that statement is also referencing t. Isn't that self-referencial?

How do I add the actual table reference into t? E.g. the `\`datasetname.tablename\`` part that points down to my table t in big query?

Comment: @Olsgaard . . . No.  There should be a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Works like charm! However, in my case in `tt.*` I got a error message `Cannot dot-star in a INT64 field`. So I just called `SELECT tt` and it worked

Comment: @SandroWiggers . . . I fixed that.